# Calculate the speed of the boat in still water?

Tags: word-problem

A motorboat spends $1$ hour and $50$ minutes sailing downstream the river for $20$ km and sailed back upstream the river.Next time it spends $54$ minutes sailing $12$ km downstream the river and 8 km upstream the river.Calculate the speed of the boat in still water and the speed of the current of the river.

Comment: This is hard to parse.  If it takes $110$ minutes to go $20$ km downstream, then going $12$ km downstream would take $\frac {12}{25}\times 110=52.8$ minutes.  So...something seems awry.

Comment: Typo:  should have written $\frac {12}{20}\times 110=66$.  The point remains the same.

Comment: I interpret there are two trips: 110 min for a trip of 20 km down and 20 km up and another of 54 min for 12 down and 8 up.

Comment: yeah thats true